# How can I get the downloading progress of a 3D asset loaded by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, download

I'm making a videogame and I have the map file that's pretty large and it takes sometime to download.
To let the user know that everything is fine and not stuck I wanted to implement a loading bar letting him know how much of the map has loaded at a certain moment.

From the "Networks" tab of my browser console I can clearly check the downloaded size of that asset and now my question is: how can i put that loaded MBs data to my script to make a progress bar?

[Screenshot to help explain me better :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSupg.png)

Thanks so much, maybe a silly question, I know.

Comment: You can use the progress event handler in Ajax request via xhr ( for download and upload progress)

Comment: Thank you, I'm still fresh on this stuff, how am I suppose to implement that? @Sanmeet

Comment: Can you provide the URL to which u are making Ajax call ? ..  
 Youu are downloading a file right ! Can you share that file ? I think I got something ...